# Host xxxx is not allowed to connect to this MySql server and class issue

Tags: c#, mysql, connection

I am currently trying to learn MySQL with C# and I've been having some problems.

```
        string currServer = w.server.Text;
        string currDatabase = w.database.Text;
        string currUser = w.uid.Text;
        string currPassword = w.password.Text;

        server = currServer;
        database = currDatabase;
        uid = currUser;
        password = currPassword;
```

This here gives me the error That I'm not allowed to connect to that host. But when I use

```
        server = "localhost";
        database = "test";
        uid = "root";
        password = "test123";
```

I am able to connect to the server. I've tried to create a new MySQL user and been Googling around a bit.

And I also have this error when I want to access my Query class to run queries I've get the error: Connection must be valid or open. 
When I use the same method in the db_connection class this does not appear.

Query.cs file:

```
public void insertToDatabase()
{
    var db_connection = new db_connection();

    string query = "UPDATE users SET facebook = 'TEST123' WHERE user_id=9";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db_connection.Connection);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Command: " + query + " executed without errors.");
}
```

db_connection.cs file:

```
public class db_connection
{
    /* ---- Database Variables for Connection ---- */
    public  MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    public void Initialize(Window w)
    {
        string currServer = w.server.Text;
        string currDatabase = w.database.Text;
        string currUser = w.uid.Text;
        string currPassword = w.password.Text;

        server = "localhost";
        database = "test";
        uid = "root";
        password = "test123";

        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    /* ---- Open connection to the database ---- */
    public bool openConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("MySQL Connection opened without errors.");
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not establish a connection to the server.");
                    break;
                case 1045:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid username or password");
                    break;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public MySqlConnection Connection
    {
        get { return this.connection; }
    }

    /* ---- Closing the connection to the database ---- */
    public bool closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("MySQL Connection shutdown without errors.");
            return true;
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Number);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* ---- Closing connection and trying to re-connect ---- */
    public bool refreshConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Restarting...");
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection re-established without errors.");
            return true;
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Number);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well it's as the error message states: inside your `insertToDatabase` you never open your connection. Also your `Initialize` method in your `db_connection` class is no substitute for a constructor if you do not call it explicitly.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. When I open a connection in the insertToDatabase it says that the connection is already open.